# What is the correct way of building a service?

Tags: angular, angular-services, circular-dependency

**Happy Monday Developers!**

I have a question for you all which I haven't been able to answer myself.

I'm currently building an application which gets a ton of data from services which on itself makes a few API requests.

Now I need to do all of these API calls before my application will be made available to the user.

Now my question is: "What is the correct way of building an application structure where you depend on data".

**Currently implemented solution:**

Every service on itself has a few functions which then create a few HTTP get requests.

I currently have a main service, which imports all other services.
I then have a ton of promises one after another controlling the flow.
Now this works nicely if I want to do this once at the beginning of my application.
But I now also want to do these same calls in the middle of running my app.
But whenever I import this main service from another service I create a circular dependency since the main service imports every service available.

**Now, what is the correct way to handle this?**
I need to have a function which I can call, which retrieves all of the data needed for my application and I should be able to call this function from any component and or service within my application without creating a circular dependency.

**How would you guys solve this? And is there a Best practice for this?**

** FYI, this is not a standard app but a 'kiosk'. We initially want to get all of the data so that the application almost never has to load. Besides when I call that function to re-retrieve all data. **

**Main service Code Sample:**

```
    constructor(
    private testservice1: TestService1,
    private testservice2: TestService2,
    private testservice3: TestService3,
    private testservice3: TestService4
) {
    this.loading = true;

    this.getApplicationLogic()
     .then(() => {
        this.loading = false;
     })

}

public getApplicationLogic() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        testservice1.getTest()
            .then(
                res => {
                    testservice1.setTestConfig(res);
                    return this.testservice2.getTest2();
                },
                msg => {
                    throw new Error(msg)
                })
            .then(
                res => {
                    testservice2.setTestConfig(res);
                    return this.testservice3.getTest3();
                },
                msg => {
                    throw new Error(msg)
                })
            .then(
                res => {
                    testservice3.setTestConfig(res);
                    resolve();
                },
                msg => {
                    throw new Error(msg)
                })
    });
}
```

Comment: do share some code .

Comment: Do you have routing in your application?

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov yes of course :)

Comment: @Rick-HashtagNetwork You can use the Routing events and resolver. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LaIAHOSKHCQ 5:54

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov That in the long run will still not make me able to create a function which I can call to again retrieve all of the data, I'd still get a circular dependancy then.

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround circular dependencies by injecting `Injector` instead of one of the services that cause the circular dependency

```ts
private testservice1:Testservice1;
constructor(/*private testservice1:Testservice1*/ injector:Injector) {
  setTimeout(() => this.testservice1 = injector.get(Testservice1));
}
```

i dont know the complexity of your code. But if you cross any circular dependency then you can apply this.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't answer my question in any way.
The essence of this question is to get to know how to properly build a service and how to make a service or similar which controls the flow of all services.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 questions:

1. How to load data from the API when the application is starting. For that you need to use the APP_INITIALIZER token. Official docs [here](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) and tutorial explained [here](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/angular-4-tutorial-run-code-during-app-initialization/).
2. Avoid circular dependency. I think your Main Service cannot (and should not) be reused. API calls, by their nature, should be asynchronous, yet it seems you are trying to run them in a specific order. It is not quite clear what you are trying to do when you say "whenever I import this main service from another service" - taking your example code, obviously none of testservices 1..4 can import main. Therefore if you have some new server (testservice5) that needs FIRST to load 1..4, then testservice5 can import Main and THEN do its own work. Even if testservice5 makes the same API call as testservice1 for example (of course it means you will have code duplication).

A better solution for (2) would be to NOT design around having services execute in a specific pre-defined order, but allow each service to fire independently of one another, store the data and have some kind of global tracker that gets updated as each service completes (returns data).

For example, at app startup say you want 4 services to complete. Fire the first one, in its result you update the flag to 1 and fire an event. Your second service listens for that event and runs. In its result you update the flag to 2, and fire the event again. Service 3 listens for that event and runs, updates the flag etc.

This way you can use all 4 services in defined order at startup, but still have each service as a separate self-contained 'thing' that you an re-use later while the app is running.

Comment: The reason for this is that I'm building a kiosk.
This kiosk will be loaded once on startup, and re-use almost all data and it never gets refreshed or anything for days.

The reason all things are chained is that they all need information from one another.

We don't want to have any loading screens.

To make it even clearer this kiosk will be used to create appointments for customers.
So I want to retrieve this information again after an appointment is created because that's the only time we want a loading screen.

Comment: This will also still not make me able to call a function which will again retrieve all of this data that we initially need.

Comment: Yes it will. But you saying it won't makes it almost impossible to understand your issue. You say "since the main service imports every service available." Well why not create a new service that is NOT imported by main, and in that service inject main and use it. Then there is no circular dependency. This new service is the one you use while the app is running.

Comment: Because almost every service needs information from another service to work properly.

Comment: If that is the case then your problem is not with Angular, but with your architecture having circular dependencies. You most probably need to create duplicates of some of your services (one version to be included in Main, and one version that you use during the app while it is running). Note that you should still use idea (1) APP_INITIALIZER to load your Main service/data when the app starts up.

Comment: Thanks a lot @rmcsharry

Answer (score 0):

Generaly I structure the services with a general appstate service which holds the global settings ( like backend server url ), an http service which deals with generic http requests eg

```
export class MyHttpService{
  constructor(
  private http: HttpClient,
  private app: AppstateService,
  private log: LogService
) { }

getRest<T>(api: string)  {
  let opts = this.getOptions();
  return this.http.get<T>(this.app.backurl + "/api/v1/" + api, opts);
}
```

and an api service which implements the high level apis eg

```
export class MyapiService {
   constructor(private myhttp: MyHttpService) {}

GetOperations(pt_id: number) {
 this.myhttp.getRest<DashboardOperations>( "GetDashboardOperations?pt_id=" 
  + pt_id ).pipe(map(resp=> resp.data));
}
```

the final component only deals with the api service to get the data with subscribe.

If you don't want your app to grab all the data each time it refreshes information you might consider using pouchdb to store the data localy and sync it with the server ( see https://www.sitepoint.com/offline-web-apps-service-workers-pouchdb/ )